# Babel: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, babeljs, decorator

I created a decorator function

```js
export function classLogger(target: any) {
    const classFunctions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype).filter(item => typeof target.prototype[item] === 'function')
    for (const propertyName of classFunctions) {
        const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target.prototype, propertyName);
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
            if (descriptor.value.constructor.name === 'Function') {
                descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
                    logArguments(propertyName, args);
                    return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
                };
            } else if (descriptor.value.constructor.name === 'AsyncFunction') {
                descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
                    logArguments(propertyName, args);
                    return await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
                };
            }
            Object.defineProperty(target.prototype, propertyName, descriptor); 
    }
}
```

And i use this function in my Javascript class

```js
@classLogger
class A extends B {
    someMethod(){
    
    }
}
```

When I try to use this

```js
new A().someMethod()
```

I have been receiving this error.
**TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function**
I am sure that this is due to some babel conversion. Because i have written test cases for the above decorator and its seems working fine. But when i used it in node project with Babel 7. It's giving me runtime error. My node version is 14.16.0. I atleast wants to know the cause of this issue.

Comment: I don't see your decorator in use in the second code snippet (i.e. I would expect to see `@classLogger` otherwise it appears you are not using the decorator).

Comment: @otto-null thanks i made an edit in the second code snippet and add the `@classLogger` as suggested by you. I am sure i am using decorator. If i don't use the decorator then i will not face any issue. But i want to use decorator with extends keyword.